Convert a dry cell circuit to work with li-ion module
I find an emergency lamp circuit,this circuit works with dry cells but I have li-ion battery and tp4056 li-ion controller module. As you can see, its inputs and outputs are on different pins. How can I change this circuit to work with tp4056 module? Thanks in advance.



That depends on whether you want it maintained or non-maintained.
